# When I text someone, they receive it from 2 numbers

Tags: iphone, contacts, messages, sms

Whenever I text or iMessage someone, they recieve it from both my number from my old phone that I transferred over, and the number on this phone. How do I make sure only 1 number is in use?

Comment: Welcome to ask different.  It's helpful to provide the device you are using and  the iOS version.  Remember, we are not there to look over your shoulder so any relevant details should be provided.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Settings app.
Then, go to the "Messages" section.
Then, tap "Send & Receive".

After that, check to make sure that you only have one number checked.